# Get operating system name (e.g. iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to detect the name of the operating system running on the device (e.g. operating-system: iOS)

I need this in Objective-C, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 NSString *strName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];  
 NSLog(@"%@", strName);//e.g. "My iPhone"   

 NSString *strSysName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];  
 NSLog(@"%@", strSysName);// e.g. @"iOS"  

 NSString *strSysVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];  
 NSLog(@"%@", strSysVersion);// e.g. @"4.0"  

 NSString *strModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];  
 NSLog(@"%@", strModel);// e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod touch"  

 NSString *strLocModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel];  
 NSLog(@"%@", strLocModel);// localized version of model
```

Answer (score -1):

*Swift 5 version*

```
let strName = UIDevice.current.name
print(strName) // e.g. "My iPhone"

let strSysName = UIDevice.current.systemName
print(strName) // e.g. "iOS"

let strSysVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
print(strName) // e.g. "4.0" 

let strModel = UIDevice.current.model
print(strName) // e.g. "iPhone", "iPod touch"  

let strLocModel = UIDevice.current.localizedModel
print(strName) // localized version of model
```